# Импорт и обработка больших объемов данных на php

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Задача заключается в импорте больших объемов данных в бд, во время импорта, или после, будет запускаться индексация полученных данных машиной elasticsearch. Время потраченное на обработку данных может быть от нескольких минут до нескольких часов.  Так вот как это делается на php? :)

Если мы будет обращаться к скрипту просто через браузер, то как минимум браузер будет просто висеть и пользователь не поймет, что происходит, так же через время сервер просто обрывает соединение, выдавая 504 ошибку.

Я так понимаю, надо реализовать обращение к скрипту асинхронно и систему отслеживания статуса выполнения операций? А как быть уверенным в том, что сервер не вырубит процесс который висит минут 40? Может кто статейку подкинет, или советом хотя бы :)

Comment: Обязательно обязательно сделать на php?

Comment: Устанавливаются правильно всевозможные таймауты PHP и веб-сервера. Лучше запускать скрипт [отдельным процессом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553905/php-how-to-start-a-detached-process) (см. php cli), который будет куда-то складывать отчет о проделанной работе. Пользователю дать возможность запрашивать эти результаты через запросы/AJAX/Commet. Ну и да, продумать и сделать максимальную кучу проверок, что в процессе ничего не отвалится.

Comment: Ну не то чтобы прям обязательно, бекенд пишется на php решили и обработку выполнять на php

Answer (score 2):

Надо будет сделать интерфейс для создания "заданий". 
Веб интерфейс - пишем в БД, что надо сделать то и то.
PHP скрипт(ы) запускается по крону и проверяет, если ли задания, и если есть - выполняет их. Сначала помечает, что задание в работе, и начинает обрабатывать данные. По окончании - пишет в бд, что задание выполнено и пишет в БД результаты. 
Зайдя в веб интерфейс можно увидеть какие задачи есть, какие выполнены, какие в процессе, какие результаты выполнения, какие отвалились в ошибкой.

Comment: Думаю хорошая идея, спасибо. Скажите как на счет использования php для длительных операций, норм решение?  Ну длительные скажем минут 30-60 +-

Comment: php можно использовать для длительных операций, главное чтобы не текла память, то есть чтобы память, которую использует скрипт, не вылезала за определенные рамки.

Comment: Можете мне еще подсказать один момент ? Импорт запускается с помощью ajax запроса на сервер и тут же начинается импорт. Но браузер зависает на время работы скрипта на сервере, я так подозреваю, что это из-за общего PID для клиента и для сервера. Если открыть в двух браузерах и в одном из них запустить импорт, а во втором обновить страницу, то второй работает без проблем, только первый висит. Можно как-то обойти зависание браузера в котором выполняется отправка запроса на импорт?

Comment: В идеале надо начинать обработку по крону. Может вот это поможет https://dron.by/post/kak-zakryt-soedinenie-i-prodolzhit-vypolnenie-skripta.html

Comment: Полезная статейка, часть функционала взял оттуда, окончательно проблему зависания решил через сброс сессии session_destroy(); Спасибо.